# Criar vários DataFrames através de iteração

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

É possível que seja criado vários DataFrames dentro de uma iteração?
estou necessitando fazer esse feito, segue o exemplo:

na iteração NUM, possuí números de 0 a 9, total 10 números.
no `for nn in NUM:` ele irá iterar renomeando o `df_nn` ficando `df_0 df_1...` até `df_9`, assim gerando 10 DataFrames diferentes, onde posso consulta cada um.

existe alguma forma de fazer isso? obrigado

```
import pandas as pd
import random

NUM = [n for n in range(10)]

for nn in NUM:
    df_nn = pd.DataFrame({
        "A":[random.random(),random.random()]
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que você está buscando um dicionário, por exemplo:

```
d = {
    n: pd.DataFrame({
        "A": [random.random(), random.random()]
    }) 
    for n in range(10)
}
```

Agora é possível acessar cada DataFrame através de sua chave correspondente (nesse exemplo, números de 0 a 9):

```
>>> d[0]
          A
0  0.592403
1  0.328729

>>> d[5]
          A
0  0.273226
1  0.188603
```

Comment: perfeito, obrigado pela sua disponibilidade, abraço